# GitLab support for Google Cloud Platform's Container Builder

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab, google-container-builder

Is it possible to link GitLab to Container Builder with full support for automated triggers for builds? If no then is this expected in the coming future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible today. We don't have definitive plans to support this on our immediate roadmap.

Comment: Can this be considered as a feature request? I have already posted this query on GCP's official Google Group but it is pending approval.

Comment: Yes, it seems like a good feature request. You can file it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) as per [this article](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)